# Salary of Junior Professor in Germany

Tags: job-search, faculty-application, germany

I checked the W1 salary of junior professors in Germany but noticed that there is no health insurance, unemployment insurance, and pension contribution.

Source : https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/beamte/bund?id=beamte-bund-2021&g=W_1&s=0&f=0&z=100&zulage=&stj=2022b&stkl=1&r=0&zkf=0

Questions- Is it true? And at what level does a junior professor start their job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Juniorprofessor is a "Beamter", which basically means you can almost not be laid off from the job, but generally "auf Zeit", which means your contract ends after a given time (typically 5 years).

Beamte in Germany are freed from public health insurance, because the state reimburses for a certain percentage of the healthcare costs (and you can - and have to - quite cheaply insure the remaining parts), and free from unemployment and pension contribution, because defacto they can't become unemployed (unless, of course, they are "auf Zeit"), and the pension is given by the state (in German difference between "Rente" and "Pension"), approx. 70% of your last salary.

Also Junior Profs only have one level W1, because they are expected to become W2 or W3 Professors later on.

Comment: The "auf Probe" is key. You should carefully consider all your options. It can be more sensible to stay in the public health insurance voluntarily until you become "Beamter auf Lebenszeit".

Comment: Several things claimed in this answer are only partially correct: Junior professors in Germany are typically "Beamte auf Zeit" rather than "Beamte auf Probe", which is a considerable difference. They get W1 salary (there is no W0). That beamte "de facto [...] can't become unemployed" is certainly not true for junior professors, and the health insurance issue is much more complicated: in additon to the important caveat mentioned by @Roland, things also become less clear if you have children or if you have any kimd of health problems (which can make private health insurance quite expensive).

Comment: Oh, and the nice pension claims that you collect as "Beamte auf Zeit" tend to become muss less worth if you happen not to become "Beamte auf Lebenszeit".

Comment: @JochenGlueck I guess the "Beamte auf Zeit" applies until the W1 professor gets tenured or the W2/W3 professor and the same with unemployment(due to a 3+3 years contract), right? Do they need to pay for health insurance from TK or AOK?

Comment: The state doesn't pay "a certain percentage of the health *insurance* costs". It reimburses you for a percentage of the actual healthcare costs incurred.

Comment: @RohanVaidya you're required to insure the remaining part of your healthcare costs which depending on your exact situation and state should be somewhere between 20% and 50%. You theoretically *can* stay in the statutory health insurance as "voluntarily insured", *however* you would need to pay the full ~15% of your salary yourself as the state does not cover the employer contribution. That'll be somewhere upwards of 700€ per month. It's usually significantly cheaper to go with private insurance.

Comment: @Maeher: Just to avoid any misunderstanding: those somewhat more than 700€ are the entire health insurance cost, not only the half that comes from having to pay for the employer contribution - so the difference between public health insurance and private health insurance will be considerably less than 700€. And as I mentioned above, when you have several children, public health insurance might even be cheaper since they'll get health insurance for free if you have public health insurance.

Comment: @JochenGlueck there may be some narrow circumstances where that is true. But for most people it won't be. Especially because (for reasons unclear) the Beihilfe percentage für yourself goes up when you have kids.  The exact details friend in the state but as an example, in NRW with at least two kids the Beihilfe pays 80% for the kids and 70% for yourself. So you only need to insure 20% and 30% respectively. In my personal case I would need to have about 10 kids for private insurance to be more expensive. If you have a non-working spouse things might be different.

Comment: @Maeher: Thanks for your response! That's a good point - I didn't know that the Beihilfe percentage changes when you have children (and that it's even 80 percent for children).

Comment: @JochenGlueck thanks a lot, now I understood Beihilfe. But if spouse is working then can children get covered by health insurance from spouse?

Comment: @RohanVaidya: That's complicated (again). The last time I looked it up, it was as follows (if I remember correctly - so please double-check with a more reliable source): if you have private health insurance and your spouse is working and has public health insurance, then your children can get public health insurance (i.e., they can get "mitversichert" with your spouse) if and only if your spouse's gross salary is higher than yours.

Comment: Rohan, but please also take @Maeher's comment into account that there's also Beihilfe for your children if your are "verbeamtet" - although I'm not sure whether it's always 80%; this might actually depend on the federal state.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, thanks a lot it's clear, during the first 3+3 years of being a junior professor, are they considered as beamter?

Comment: @Rohan: Yes, junior professors in Germany are typically "Beamte of Zeit", i.e., they have the status "Beamte" for the time while they are junior professor. (Although there might be some exceptions.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you so much for entire discussion and providing the meaningful information.

Comment: Another thing that is only partially correct: The pension is not always "approx. 70% of the last salary" but it is "x*1.79375% of the last salary" where x is the number of full-time equivalent years you worked as a Beamter.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answer by one aspect:

If you terminate your employment as a "Beamter" (whether due to expiry of the junior professorship, or any other reason, including voluntarily), you will be retroactively insured in the pension insurance. However, the insurance amount will be computed based on your gross salary as a Beamter, that is, it will be less if you had been employed as a regular employee with the same *net* salary (as in that case, the gross salary would have been higher, due to precisely those deductions). So it is not a good deal. (In fact, I would claim "Beamter auf Zeit" is never a good deal, unless you transition into a lifetime Beamter employment afterwards.)

On the other hand, if your Beamter status is terminated, you did not have unemployment insurance, so you would immediately fall into social welfare. (This is of course only relevant if you intend and are allowed to stay in Germany after that, and don't terminate because of another job.)

Comment: thanks for making the point. From a health insurance point of view, it's true. From a pension insurance point of view, if the junior professor is not confirmed, then will the person will be eligible for a pension based on the last salary? For, unemployment benefits, is there any possibility of getting some compensation?

Comment: @Rohan The state will retroactively pay into the pension insurance, with the amount of pension paid into the insurance computed from the total salary -- just as if you had been employed with that very same total salary (*before* subtractions) as a normal employee. (Note that this is a bad deal, for several reasons.) As for unemployment benefits - no. ("Beamter auf Zeit" is in some sense a fundamentally flawed concept, because the very concept of "Beamter" is based on it being for lifetime.)